# I am getting this error in mssql - No primary key Referenced

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm getting the error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'EVENT' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__BOOKING__571DF1D5'.

I can't execute Booking Table!

Mssql Script:

```
CREATE TABLE TOUR (
  TourName   NVARCHAR(100) 
, DESCRIPTION    NVARCHAR(500)
, PRIMARY KEY (TourName)
);


CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
  ClientID   INT 
, Surname   NVARCHAR(100) 
, GivenName   NVARCHAR(100)
, Gender      NVARCHAR(1) 
, PRIMARY KEY  (ClientID) 
);

CREATE TABLE EVENT (
  TourName  NVARCHAR(100)
, EventMonth   NVARCHAR(3)
, EventDay      INT
, EventYear   INT 
, Fee      MONEY 
, PRIMARY KEY  (TourName, EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay) 
, FOREIGN KEY (TourName) REFERENCES TOUR (TourName)
);
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING (
  ClientID     INT
, TourName     NVARCHAR(100)
, EventMonth   NVARCHAR(3)
, EventDay     INT
, EventYear    INT 
, Payment      MONEY 
, DateBooked   DATE NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY  (ClientID, TourName, EventMonth, EventDay, EventYear)
, FOREIGN KEY (ClientID) REFERENCES CLIENT (ClientID)
, FOREIGN KEY (TourName) REFERENCES TOUR (TourName)
, FOREIGN KEY (EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay) 
    REFERENCES EVENT (EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay)
);
```

Comment: The error is tellin g you the problem. The PK on your table, `EVENT` is made up of the columns `TourName`, `EventYear`, `EventMonth`, and `EventDay` but the FK in the table `BOOKING` only has the columns `EventYear`, `EventMonth`, and `EventDay`; `TourName` is missing. Though having that many columns in your PK is likely a design flaw, if I am honest.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I don't like the design either...

Comment: @Larnu I wouldn't say it's a design flaw, as far as relational theory is concerned then it very well may take that many columns to uniquely identify something. The main flaw here is splitting dates into three columns

Comment: @Charlieface I didn't say it *is* just that it's likely. I'm also, however, not a fan of "natural" keys; it's often far easier to maintain a separate column for the key, meaning you don't have to duplicate multiple columns across tables, and then you can create a separate `UNIQUE INDEX`/`CONSTRAINT` on your "natural" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key reference is:

```
FOREIGN KEY (EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay) 
    REFERENCES EVENT (EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay)
```

The PRIMARY KEY is:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (TourName, EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay)
```

These are not the same.  Presumably, you want:

```
FOREIGN KEY (EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay) 
    REFERENCES EVENT (TourName, EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay)
```

That said, I would suggest that you use identity columns for your primary keys.  They are a tad more efficient in indexes.  More importantly, you don't have to duplicate all the information everywhere to refer to an event.  Just an `EventId`.  I would also go for a `TourId` as well.

Comment: I want to use EventID and TourID, but we are told to new create new keys...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the end:

```
, FOREIGN KEY (EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay) 
  REFERENCES EVENT (EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay)
```

There's no key `(EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay)` in the `EVENT` table. Change to:

```
, FOREIGN KEY (TourName, EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay) 
  REFERENCES EVENT (TourName, EventYear, EventMonth, EventDay)
```